# Blocking of tf.contrib.StagingArea get() and put() operations

Tags: tensorflow

**Work environment**

- TensorFlow release version : 1.3.0-rc2
- TensorFlow git version : v1.3.0-rc1-994-gb93fd37
- Operating System : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

**Problem Scenario**

I am using TensorFlow StagingArea ops for increasing the efficiency of my input pipeline. Here is a part of my code snippet which constructs the input pipeline :

```
  train_put_op_list = []
    train_get_op_list = []
    val_put_op_list = []
    val_get_op_list = []
    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()) as vscope:
        for i in range(4):
            with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
                with tf.name_scope('GPU-Tower-%d'%i) as scope:
                    trainstagingarea = tf.contrib.staging.StagingArea(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32],
                                                                 shapes=[[64, 221, 221, 3],[64]],
                                                                      capacity=0)
                    valstagingarea = tf.contrib.staging.StagingArea(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32],
                                                                      shapes=[[128, 221, 221, 3],[128]],
                                                                      capacity=0)
                    train_put_op_list.append(trainstagingarea.put(train_iterator.get_next()))
                    val_put_op_list.append(valstagingarea.put(val_iterator.get_next()))
                    train_get_op_list.append(trainstagingarea.get())
                    val_get_op_list.append(valstagingarea.get())
                    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                        worktype = tf.get_variable("wt",[], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=False)
                    workcondition = tf.equal(worktype, 1)
                    #elem = tf.cond(workcondition, lambda: train_iterator.get_next(), lambda: val_iterator.get_next())
                    elem = tf.cond(workcondition, lambda: train_get_op_list[i], lambda: val_get_op_list[i])
                    # This is followed by the network construction and optimizer
```

Now at the time of execution, I first run the `put()` ops a couple of times and then go on to run the iterations. It is shown below :

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        sess.run(iterator_training_op)
        sess.run(iterator_validation_op)
        sess.run(tf.assign(worktype, 0))
        for i in range(4):
            sess.run(train_put_op_list)
            sess.run(val_put_op_list)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
        epoch = 0
        iter = 0
        previous = 0
        while(epoch<10):
            try:
                if(PROCESSINGTYPE is 'validation'):
                    sess.run(val_put_op_list)
                    [val_accu, summaries, numsamp] = sess.run([running_accuracy, validation_summary_op, processed])
                    previous+=numsamp
                    print("Running Accuracy = {} : Number of sample processed = {} ".format(val_accu, previous))
                else:
                    sess.run(train_put_op_list)
                    [loss_value, _, train_accu, summaries, batch_accu, numsamp] = sess.run([total_loss, apply_gradient_op, running_accuracy, training_summary_op, batch_accuracy, pr\
ocessed])
                    #Remaining part of the code (not important for question)
```

**Problem Description**

The use of StagingArea improves the speed substantially (almost 3-4 times).
However, the code hangs due to some block. I am not sure if the block comes from `get()` or `put()` operations. Here is the actual output :

```
# Validation is done first and the following is the output
Running Accuracy = 0.0 : Number of sample processed = 512
Running Accuracy = 0.00390625 : Number of sample processed = 1024
Running Accuracy = 0.0 : Number of sample processed = 1536
Running Accuracy = 0.001953125 : Number of sample processed = 2048
# The code hangs here
```

You can notice that in the beginning of `tf.Session() as sess:`, the `get()` and `put()` ops were run for `4` times. The output is limited to 4 lines as well. This means that, 
`sess.run(val_put_op_list)` within the `while` loop does not do anything. So, when the `get()` is called by `sess.run(running_accuracy)...`, the `StagingArea` is found empty after `4` lines and hence a blocking happens.

- Am I correct in my analysis of the problem ?
- What is the correct way to use the `get()` and `put()` ops here ?
- If `StagingArea` is full and `put()` is blocked, would that also block the whole code ? TensorFlow documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: it's like a regular queue -- using "get" on empty Stage or "put" on full Stage will hang your session.run. Did you see this example of usage [tf_cnn_benchmarks.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py)? Note that it has extra logic to start queue runners for the dataset

Comment: But none of that is happening here. The capacity of each staging area is `5` . In the beginning 4 `put()` ops are run and then one `put` op is run within the loop. Then a `get()` op is run followed by another `put` op. 
Moreover if u read my question carefully and study the output, you will see my problem

Comment: oh, I didn't study the code, that was just about your last question about what happens when staging area is full

Comment: Any thoughts then ?

Comment: Maybe you could isolate a problem a bit better (ie using tf.Print)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/13684. This resolves some deadlocks and will likely go into 1.4.0. Disclaimer: am not a tensorflower.

Comment: This apparently hasn't made it into release 1.4.1 yet, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like this has been added to 1.5.0-rc0.